# Qt. Реализация гаджета рабочего стола

Tags: c++, qt

Возник вопрос, возможно ли реализовать такую программу что бы:

1. Она фиксировалась на рабочем столе.
2. Не отображалсь на панели задач и в панели ALT + TAB.

(Например календарь, который всегда находиться на рабочем столе)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в ExStyle нужно добавить флаг WS_EX_NOACTIVATE плюс Style добавить флаг WS_POPUP
Допустим так:

```
HWND desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
// desktop = GetWindow(desktop , GW_CHILD);
HWND w = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_NOACTIVATE , "#32770", "MyWindow",
  WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,/*coords*/800,100, 1000, 600, desktop,0/*menu*/, hInstance, 0 );
```

Окно можно закрепить на рабочем столе, присвоив в parent хандл рабочего стола. Класс окна можно использовать свой. Если строку разкоментировать окно становится TopMost почему-то. Что б окно было "дочерним" обязятельно наличие WS_CHILD либо WS_POPUP флага. Осталось подобрать параметры что б окно было не TOPMOST.